# Unknown symbol x (err 0)

Tags: export, symbols

I am trying to export a variable from RBT driver module to RBprobe driver module and I see the below warning while building them together:

Unknown symbol x (err 0)

I have used the EXPORT_SYMBOL function in RBT Driver module to export a variable say 'x'. Now in the RBprobe driver I have  declared 'x' using "extern".
With this I should be able to use this symbol. But I still get the above error.

My Understanding:

When we build a kernel module, a symbol table file (Module.symvers)  gets generated which contains a list of all exported symbols from a kernel build. 
Since, I am building both the kernel modules together (in order rbt530_dev.o  RBprobe.o) using single make file I guess the Module.symvers of RBprobe is replacing the one generated from rbt530_dev.o build. 
Hence the exported symbols dont appear to RBprobe driver.

Things I have tried:

1. Created two separate directories and build RBT driver module separately. Then copy-paste Module.symvers of RBT module to RBprobe. Now I built the module it still shows the same warning. 
   There are no compilation errors.
2. Used make variable KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS but this did not work in my favour.

There is another way I read in the document to solve this issue wherein we build a top-level kbuild file but I am struggling to build the same.

In case anyone knows a better approach to solve this issue let me know. Also, if I am going wrong or missing anything let me know.